# Dynamic URL based on date and time for Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to create a dynamic iframe that loads a page that is named after the date in yyyy-mm-dd format with the addition of +AM and +PM added at the end.
Example: https://example.com/display/stuff/2016-10-02+AM

This is what I have so far.. I'm not getting any syntax errors but it won't render.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate;
    var mm = today.getMonth;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear;
    var h = h > 12 ? h - 12 + 'PM' : h + 'AM';
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + '+' + h;
</script>
document.body.innerHTML = ('<iframe src="https://example.com/display/stuff/\'today'/"'</iframe>')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. JavaScript outside of a script element won't be doin' much. 2. Go research how concatenating text literals and variable contents works, that is something very basic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var tmpHour =  today.getHours();
    var h =tmpHour > 12 ?  tmpHour - 12 + 'PM' :  tmpHour + 'AM';
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var dateString = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + '+' + h;

   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://example.com/display/stuff/' + dateString);
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
</script>
```

You had several syntax errors, and mostly you forgot to invoke the Date functions - you did not add ();

Also know that the month is always returnd -1 (it is from 0 to 11 instead of 1 to 12)

Answer (score 0):

You search for something like that?:

```js
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate;
    var mm = today.getMonth;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear;
    var h = h > 12 ? h - 12 + 'PM' : h + 'AM';
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + '+' + h;
document.body.innerHTML = ('<iframe src="https://example.com/display/stuff/' + today + '"></iframe>')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a few things.

```
date.getDate
```

This is a function so should be called like

```
date.getDate()
```

Also your calling your javascript code outside of the `<script>` tag which won't be evaluated.

Here's the semi working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var h = h > 12 ? h - 12 + 'PM' : h + 'AM';
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + '+' + h;
    document.body.innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://example.com/display/stuff/'+ today+'"></iframe>';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are calling `document.body.innerHTML` outside the script tag. So it won't be parsed as JS code.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate;
    var mm = today.getMonth;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear;
    var h = h > 12 ? h - 12 + 'PM' : h + 'AM';
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + '+' + h;
    document.body.innerHTML = ('<iframe src="https://example.com/display/stuff/\'today'/"'</iframe>')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```