# How to change iframe source depending on the browser time?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am making a site that displays trailers of TV Shows, but one thing: I want the trailers to play depending on time. Like the today's date is: 10 August, so I want to display the trailer of EPISODE 1 and if today's date is: 11 August, it will display EPISODE 2's trailer and so on.
(I dont want it to change the season, only the episode)
**IFRAME CODE:**

```
<iframe src="https://example.org/imdb/tmdb/trailers/?id={ID}&s={SEASON}&e={EPISODE}" width="100%"
height="500px">
```

(I would prefer JS answers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing iframe src with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816566/dynamic-url-based-on-date-and-time-for-iframe

Comment: Thanks! Still answers will be appreciated.

Comment: The answers are in the the linked questions. You might actually have to do some thinking yourself though.

Comment: Yes, I did & posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Heretic Monkey!
I was able to generate this code:

```css
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var tmpHour =  today.getHours();
    var h =tmpHour > 12 ?  tmpHour - 12 + 'PM' :  tmpHour + 'AM';
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var dateString = dd;

   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://example.org/imdb/tmdb/trailers/?id=123&s=1&e=' + dateString);
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Today's Trailer:</h1>
</body>
</html>
```